# Laravel em hospedagem só funciona a home

Tags: laravel

Eu segui um tutorial aonde as pasta do laravel vai fora do public_html e faz alteração do public_html/index.php pra

```
require __DIR__.'/../projeto/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../projeto/bootstrap/app.php';
```

e o projeto/server.php pra

```
    if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/../public_html'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/../public_html/index.php';
```

funciona o meusite.com/ mas se eu coloco meusite.com/login da error 404, o que estou fazendo errado?

meu formato de pasta ta assim

-projeto

--app

--boostrap

-public_html

--css

--img

--js

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive esse problema em um servidor locaweb e resolvi da seguinte maneira.

Mantenha a estrutura do laravel igual ao que era.

Edite o htacess
Se caso não for locaweb, retire as primeiras linhas.

```
##### LOCAWEB - NAO REMOVER #####
AddHandler php56-script .php
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/seusite/
##### LOCAWEB - NAO REMOVER #####

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://seu site/$1 [R,L] #aqui força https
```

esse é o htacess da raiz e dentro de public use o htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sicadergs.com.br/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Eu entrei em contato com o suporte eles me auxiliaram, meu vps é da hostgator, mesmo assim muito obrigado pela resposta